# Fail to update record field of Enum type

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am trying to do a Patch to my record using postman web api but somehow the salesOrderStatusId doesn't get updated, the property is of an enum type.

Patch:

```
{
    "SalesOrderNumber": "S0001",
    "salesOrderStatusId": 2,
    "ApptType": false
},
```

Property:

```
public Nullable<SalesOrderStatus> SalesOrderStatusId { get; set; }
```

Action:

```
[ActionName("DefaultAction")]
public override HttpResponseMessage Patch(int SalesOrderId, Delta<SalesOrder> NewSalesOrder)
{
    var SalesOrder = _uow.Repository<SalesOrder>().Find(SalesOrderId);

    if (SalesOrder == null)
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

    NewSalesOrder.Patch(SalesOrder);

    SalesOrder.ObjectState = ObjectState.Modified;

    _uow.Repository<SalesOrder>().Update(SalesOrder);

    try
    {
        _uow.Save();

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, SalesOrder);
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Web API are you using? If it's still using the standard DataContractJsonSerializer, your incoming JSON deserialization will be case sensitive. The "s" in salesOrderStatusId is lower case vs your model which is upper case. This shouldn't be a problem with the JSONSerializer though.

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this resolved? I have the same issue myself...